# Creating Duplicate Entry when updating post

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, posts

I am using this code snippet to add the custom meta entered by customer from the custom field license_plate when they add a new vehicle to their account. how ever upon saving the post for whatever reason a second time - it will add the same meta again ...this does not happen a third or fourth time it stops at 2 entries meaning duplicate - note: when erasing re-saving it will display the license plate 2x at most after updating many times. I believe there needs to be something in this code at the update_post part but how to code this I do not know. Can someone help me with this where it can check is the post title has already been filled in previous and then leave alone if that is true.

I am using cpt-UI for the custom posts and ACF for the fields.

```
// Auto-populate post title with ACF fields created before hand
function engx_auto_generate_vehicles_post_title( $value, $post_id, $field ) {

//$date = strtotime(get_field('license_plate', $post_id));
$license = get_field('license_plate', $post_id). ' ' . $value; //get the value of the meta inputed by customer

$title = $license;   //actual usage
//$formatted_date = date_i18n('d M Y', $date);                       //saved for use case time
//$title = $formatted_date .' - '. $license;                         // this was kept as example with multiple meta usage


$slug = sanitize_title( $title );                                   //save meta

$postdata = array(
     'ID'          => $post_id,
     'post_title'  => $title,                                       //Use the meta $title as the New auto generated Title for the newly created post the customer just created
     'post_type'   => 'vehicles',                                   //The Custom Post Type Name
     'post_name'   => $slug
);

wp_update_post( $postdata );

return $value;

}
//add_filter('acf/update_value/name=date', 'jb_update_postdata', 10, 3);
add_filter('acf/update_value/name=license_plate', 'engx_auto_generate_vehicles_post_title',     10, 3);     //acf hook from where to fetch this specific field data - is from acf documentation
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out found the peice of code needed to verify if empty first as     follows

```
//replace 
wp_update_post( $postdata );

//with
if ( isset( $_POST['post_title'] ) && empty( $_POST['post_title'] ) ) {
  wp_update_post( $postdata );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably better off using [`acf/save_post`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-save_post/) to handle events when creating new or updating existing vehicle posts...

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-save_post/

See example below...

```php
// process vehicle details when saving the post
add_action('acf/save_post', 'vehicle_save_post', 20);
    
// vehicles post type save action
function vehicle_save_post ($post_id) {
    
    // check we are on vehicles post type else return early
    if(get_post_type($post_id) <> 'vehicles') return;
    
    // get current saved value for license_plate acf field
    $license = get_field('license_plate', $post_id);
    
    // get our vehicle post object
    $vehicle = get_post($post_id);
    
    // temporally remove the action
    remove_action('acf/save_post', 'vehicle_save_post', 20);
    
    // update the current post object
    $vehicle->post_title = $license;
    $vehicle->post_name  = sanitize_title($license);
    
    // update post with updated vehicle object
    wp_update_post($vehicle);
    
    // do more updates here like update_post_meta etc...
    
    // re add the action
    add_action('acf/save_post', 'vehicle_save_post', 20);
    
    // finally, return
    return;
    
}
```